# How can an IT undergrad become a Data Scientist.?

Tags: computer-science, data

I know asking undergrad questions are not well received here. But I don't know any other place have the standard of this place.

I am a Bachelor of Information technology student. I am maintaining a second upper GPA at school. My target is to become a data scientist. And this is my plan. 
 I will learn data science basics on coursera. I will start with a diploma in applied statistics parallel to my final year of my degree. Then I will go for a M.Sc in CS. Where I come from doesn't have undergraduate/pg math degrees available for me (only for few merit students who enter state universities get to those). I will do a research more related to data science. (Not sure if I can do it in a M.Sc in CS)
 I know there should be opinions, and this question won't lead to a one single perfect solution. But I'm asking if you can tell me if this is a good plan.?

Comment: You do not need a degree in data science to become a data scientist.

Comment: As a side note, I suspect that masters in statistics will be more relevant than most CS masters (unless you find some kind of dedicated data analysis CS program).

Comment: As Aleksandr Blekh's answer indicates, there *is* a better place for this question, and even if there weren't you are unlikely to get the kind of academic advising you need in this venue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered several related questions on the *Data Science SE* site some time ago. I hope that my answers are relevant to your situation and will be helpful. Wishing you best of luck!

- [Graduate Degree Choices for Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/3737/2452)
- [Starting my career as Data Scientist, is Software Engineering experience required?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/742/2452)
- [Data Science Project Ideas](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/843/2452)

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: How can one become a data scientist?

**Answer**: Call yourself one.

That's what everyone else does. (Yes, cynical, I know.)

Comment: Yeah ,Plan B :D